# Is there a way to order array by Virtual Property in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a column 'pages' with values like "1-3, 4, 5, 6-10, 12-15" etc. and I would like to sort my array by them.

But the result is not correct: "12-15, 1-3, 4, 5, 6-10".

So I figured out I'm gonna create virtual property like this:

```
protected $_virtual = ['proper_order'];

protected function _getProperOrder()
{
    return intval(strtok($this->_properties['pages'],  '-'));
}
```

But is there any way to sort array using Virtual Property at all?

Comment: you have 2 options, first one is to fetch all results from db to  array and then sort them, here you can use `usort` and yours `->properOrder` field. Second is to sort at db level using string function like `substr`, `pos` то cut first number

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I got this. I used Collection and it's working.

```
$collection = new Collection($articles);
$result = $collection->sortBy('proper_order', SORT_ASC);
```

Comment: Depending on how you get the `$articles` variable, you might just be able to call `sortBy` as part of that process. e.g. `$articles = $this->Articles->find()->where([...])->sortBy(...);`